# Which hostname to use when running docker-compose inside gitlab.com (public version)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab

I can't figure out which hostname to use to access containers that were started with docker-compose inside docker-in-docker service on Gitlab.com?

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: docker/compose

stages:
  - test_api

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"


before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker-compose down
    - docker-compose up -d

test_api:
  stage: test_api
  image: stoplight/prism:latest
  script:
    - apk add curl
    - curl 127.0.0.1:4010/pets -XGET
```

I just cannot figure out what should the hostname be set to in URL where I am using curl to send get request? Neither `docker` nor `localhost` work, server is not available.

And docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  prism:
    image: stoplight/prism:latest
    command: >
      mock -p 4010 --host 0.0.0.0 
        https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/examples/v3.0/petstore-expanded.yaml
    ports:
      - "4010:4010"
    restart: always
```